# Do classes inherit protocols in objective-c?

Tags: ios4, inheritance, protocols, ipad

I have a class that implements a protocol .  In MyProtocol, I have two properties:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
    @property(nonatomic, retain) NSObject *stuff;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *stringStuff;
@end
```

My class implements the protocol as shown

Header .h

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController <MyProtocol>
...
```

Implementation.m

```
@implementation MyClass
    @synthesize stuff;
    @synthesize stringStuff;
...
```

I have a class that inherits from MyClass...

```
@interface MySubClass : MyClass
```

When I try to access stuff and stringStuff in MySubClass, I get an error saying that MySubClass does not have a member named 'stringStuff.'

How can I get the child classes to be able to access these members of the parent class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use property access in the subclass, were you trying to access the ivars directly?

Edit: Just realised I didn't answer your original question. Yes, if a superclass implements a protocol then the subclass will too.

Comment: I want to get to the stringStuff that is stored in the MyClass, from MySubClass....it is not letting me do that.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? What is the exact error you are getting? Is it a compiler warning, or a runtime error?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to access the ivars from the superclass directly, use the accessor methods: eg. self.stuff and self.stringStuff instead of stuff and stringStuff. Hope this helps.

-R